How to validate configuration in Terraform before deployment?
I have a configuration of a service called loki.yml. I do not want to deploy invalid configuration. To check the configuration, I should execute the command loki -log.level debug -verify-config -config.file ./loki.yml.
How should I write Terraform configuration to execute this command?
I tried reading:

https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-validate
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/validate
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/checks

and researching:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/nazarewk-iac/custom/latest/docs/resources/custom_resource
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hkak03key/command/latest/docs/data-sources/command
https://registry.terraform.io/search/providers?q=command

Could someone share how this should be written? Are there best practices for configuration validation - should this maybe be preferred to be done outside terraform with a Makefile? This is my current configuration:
check "loki_config_is_ok" {
  data "??" "??" {
    ?? get exit code of command ??
  }

  assert {
    condition = ??.exit_code is not 0
    error_message = "dont"
  }
}

resource "nomad_job" "loki" {
  jobspec = file("./loki.nomad.hcl")
  hcl2 {
    vars     = { mark = file("./loki.yml") }
  }
  # disallow deployment if config is invalid ?
  depends_on = [loki_config_is_ok]
}



Only validation
You can prevent deploying an invalid configuration using a plain data "external" block if you're OK with just failing the plan step entirely when validation fails. Assuming loki indicates success by exit code (which it should and seems to), the following will be sufficient:
data "external" "loki_config_validation" {
    program = ["loki", "-verify-config", ...]  # whatever args you need
}

Yes, that's it. I'm not ready to install loki toolset now, so let's use simple exit 1 script instead:
data "external" "loki_config_validation" {
    program = ["bash", "-c", "echo FAIL >&2 && exit 1"]
}

Using terraform 1.9.4 and provider hashicorp/external 2.3.3 I get the following output block when running terraform plan:

╷
│ Error: External Program Execution Failed
│ 
│   with data.external.loki_config,
│   on data.tf line 26, in data "external" "loki_config":
│   26:   program = ["bash", "-c", "echo FAIL >&2 && exit 1"]
│ 
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute the program.
│ 
│ Program: /usr/bin/bash
│ Error Message: FAIL
│ 
│ State: exit status 1
╵

Plan is not generated, this is a hard failure. So if your loki command exits with non-zero code, validation fails and deployment is prevented. You don't need any shenanigans to validate this configuration. You don't need related assert or precondition blocks either - it will just abort planning entirely on failure.
It will also display the stderr of that command on failure. "Error Message:"  line will contain the error. If your program writes to stdout, you can simply redirect it with >&2.
Capturing output
First, I agree that a script in this answer is a good solution to the general problem "I want to run an external script with arguments and read the stdout". I'm not even sure it's worth introducing a provider dependency.
However, there are existing (and quite popular, according to their download stats) providers as well. I found these two: data and resource.
They are not a silver bullet. These modules support capturing exit code and stdout/stderr, also providing you a choice whether to abort on failure. However, shell escaping now comes into play: when your arguments aren't "simple" (e.g. there's no need to escape a resource ID), you need a generic escaper. If you want to run in a fully managed manner, here's a null resource from the same provider that performs shell escaping. It also handles \ vs \\ problem (note that it isn't the provider messing up with slashes - it's the shell interpreting \\ as a single backslash).
Note that this module runs in a shell, as opposed to data "external" invoking an executable directly.
It would look something like this:
module "shell_data_hello" {
  source  = "Invicton-Labs/shell-data/external"
  command_unix = <<EOF
  echo 'failed \\ slash' ${module.escape_var.unix} >&2 && exit 1
EOF
}

module "escape_var" {
  source = "Invicton-Labs/shell-escape/null"
  string = var.to_be_escaped
}

variable "to_be_escaped" {
  type = string
  default = "Hi! See $ and \\ characters and _ _ spaces"
}

output "command_out" {
  value = module.shell_data_hello.stdout
}

Running plan on this produces:
╷
│ Error: External Program Execution Failed
│ 
│   with module.shell_data_hello.data.external.run,
│   on .terraform/modules/shell_data_hello/main.tf line 76, in data "external" "run":
│   76:   program = local.is_windows ? ["powershell.exe", "${abspath(path.module)}/run.ps1"] : [local.var_unix_interpreter, "${abspath(path.module)}/run.sh"]
│ 
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute the program.
│ 
│ Program: /bin/sh
│ Error Message: failed \ slash Hi! See $ and \ characters and _ _ spaces
│ State: exit status 1

Replacing exit 1 with exit 0 and removing stderr redirection produces expected output:
Changes to Outputs:
  + command_out    = "failed \\ slash Hi! See $ and \\ characters and _ _ spaces"

Make sure not to over-escape: if there are some shell syntax elements, you shouldn't escape them.

Hi. Thanks, that was the answer I was really hoping for. fyi using base64 is just much simpler for escaping and de-escaping any text than another module.

@KamilCuk And base64 is a really great idea, could you edit this part into your or my answer?

Given that you want to execute an external script, you should leverage a data external block. You can then use the result of this block in either a check block (which will return a warning if the condition is not satisfied) or in a resource's precondition (which will error out if the condition is not satisfied):
Here's an example:
main.tf:
data "external" "example" {
    program = ["bash", "${path.module}/foo.sh"]
}

check "health_check" {
  assert {
    condition     = data.external.example.result.exit_code == "0"
    error_message = "data external example returned an unhealthy status code"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "name" {
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
        condition     = data.external.example.result.exit_code == "0"
        error_message = "data external example returned an unhealthy status code"
    }
  }
}

with foo.sh:
#!/bin/bash
jq -r -n '{"exit_code":"0"}'

terraform plan outputs:
# null_resource.name will be created
+ resource "null_resource" "name" {
    + id = (known after apply)
  }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

with foo.sh:
#!/bin/bash
jq -r -n '{"exit_code":"1"}'

terraform plan outputs:
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Warning: Check block assertion failed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 7, in check "health_check":
│    7:     condition     = data.external.example.result.exit_code == "0"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.external.example.result.exit_code is "1"
│ 
│ data external example returned an unhealthy status code
╵
╷
│ Error: Resource precondition failed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 15, in resource "null_resource" "name":
│   15:         condition     = data.external.example.result.exit_code == "0"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.external.example.result.exit_code is "1"
│ 
│ data external example returned an unhealthy status code

so in your scenario the script you use could look something like this:
#!/bin/bash
loki -log.level debug -verify-config -config.file ./loki.yml
jq -r -n --arg loki_exit_code "$?" '{"exit_code":$loki_exit_code}'


If you're looking to use the same assertion more than once, or indeed if you want to setup multiple assertionts, you could leverage a local value:
data "external" "example" {
    program = ["bash", "${path.module}/foo.sh"]
}

locals {
  assertions = [{
    "condition": data.external.example.result.exit_code
    "value": "0"
    "error_message": "data external example returned an unhealthy status code"
  }]
}

check "health_check" {
  assert {
    condition     = local.assertions[0].condition == local.assertions[0].value
    error_message = local.assertions[0].error_message
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "name" {
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
        condition     = local.assertions[0].condition == local.assertions[0].value
        error_message = local.assertions[0].error_message
    }
  }
}


I really do not like that everything has to be a json in terraform. Is there a way around it? Bottom line, I will write a wrapper like python -c 'import sys,json,subprocess;p=subprocess.run(sys.argv[1:],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,text=True);print(json.dumps({"exit_code":p.returncode,"stdout":p.stdout.rstrip()}))' and then use it for everything terraform related. Are you aware if there is such a ready-to-use wrapper? Writing it, as you have written in your question, is just trivial and repeatable.

@KamilCuk yeah I know it sucks, but if you're using data external the output has to be JSON

Well, 0 and 1 are valid JSON. Does terraform need a JSON object specifically, or can you just echo $? and remove .exit_code lookups down the road?

@STerliakov when using data external the program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values

IS it possible not to repeat myself? In the precondition { block there is the same. Is there something like precondition { check.health_check.assert } ?

Does terraform need a JSON object specificall Not only that, it has to be exactly map of  strings to strings. So it can't be {"exit_code": 0} it has to be {"exit_code": "0"}. It is surprising for me that such a simple and obvious to me use case as checking configuration file with external command requires multiple hops and several head scratches. I am basically porting a Makefile with a bunch of curl to terraform - it is not obvious how to model relations in terraform.

@KamilCuk I've added a way on how you could achieve DRY when using assertions. But the block itself needs to be spelled out.

I find it rather amusing that such a popular project like terraform can't just run a command and capture output. To solve your issue, create the following python file:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import contextlib
import json
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import tempfile


@contextlib.contextmanager
def maybe_with_tempfile(content):
    if content:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("wt") as f:
            f.write(content)
            f.flush()
            yield f.name
    else:
        yield ""


def eprint(*args):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-t",
    "--tempfile",
    help="Replace {} in the command with the name of a temporary file created with the specified content.",
)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--shell", help="Run shell")
parser.add_argument("cmd", nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()
cmd = shlex.split(args.cmd[0]) if len(args.cmd) == 1 else args.cmd
with maybe_with_tempfile(args.tempfile) as fname:
    cmd = [x.replace("{}", fname) for x in cmd]
    if args.shell:
        cmd = ["bash", "-euopipefail", "-c", " ".join(shlex.quote(x) for x in cmd)]
    eprint()
    eprint(f"+ {cmd}")
    pp = subprocess.run(cmd, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(json.dumps({"exitcode": str(pp.returncode), "stdout": pp.stdout}))
if pp.returncode:
    eprint(pp.stdout)
exit(pp.returncode)

With it you are able to run any program and assert that the result is non-zero and capture the program output. So the folloing constructs are possible, like generating job specification using jinja2:
data "external" "lokimemcached_nomad_yml" {
  program = [
    "./terraform_runner.py",
    "jinja2 lokimemcached.nomad.hcl.j2"
  ]
}
resource "nomad_job" "lokimemcached" {
  jobspec = data.external.lokimemcached_nomad_yml.result.stdout
}

Or as required, checking that a particular condition is true:

data "external" "loki_config" {
  program = [
    "./terraform_runner.py",
    "loki -log.level=debug -verify-config -config.expand-env -config.file=./loki.yml"
  ]
}
resource "nomad_job" "loki" {
  jobspec = file("./loki.nomad.hcl")
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition     = data.external.loki_config.result.exitcode == "0"
      error_message = ""
    }
  }
}

It has taken me like an hour to write the script. It would be absolutely amazing if someone would write it in terraform and publish to the terraform hub. I am surprised there is nothing commonly used there to fit my case already.

I'm feeling a bit off context here, but I just checked, and data "external" already blocks plan/apply if their exit status is non-zero. program = ["bash", "-c", "exit 1"] makes the plan fail, as expected, If your purpose is just to abort plan/apply if validation fails, you can get rid of all these wrappers and just call loki directly there (and also remove precondition block completely). It won't be completely equivalent to your code, but will fully satisfy "do not deploy invalid configuration" - your terraform plan will die with Error: External Program Execution Failed

(it's a bit difficult to put as a comment, I'll try to make a full answer today - please LMK if you have other requirements I'm missing)

And there are TF providers in wild that do the same as your script (stdout & stderr capturing): data and resource

If they are, I would be happy to use. And yes, it fails on failure, which is added value. Should I prefer shell data or shell resource? How do I pass stdin? How do I pass properly escaped arguments? I do not see terraform shlex.quote function.

Also looks like Invicton-Labs/shell-data/external is replacing \\ by single \. This is braking my regexes. I got around it by using base64.
